# Why water looks purple in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image: Screen Shot] I'm learning Unity 5 and I tried to add some water to my scene so I go to `assets->Import Packages->Environment` & after that I go to `Standard Assets->Environment->Water->Water->Prefabs->WaterProDaytime`.

But I don't know why it looks purple. Sounds really weird ! Can someone explain it to me why it happens and how can I fix that ? Thx...

Comment: Lighting probably.

Comment: Could you maybe upload a picture to your question to see what it looks like?

Comment: Sounds like a shader problem. Can you put up screenshot?

Comment: As a note: this pink texture is unitys way of saying that the desired texture is missing or there is no texture assigned (when dealing with textures of materials).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like your shader is missing a link or doesn't exist.

Find your shader and reassign it in the inspector :)